# MySQL merge two queries (and more)

Tags: mysql, merge, view

I have a series of views/queries that eventually lead to my desired view in the mysql database. To simplify I have the following scheme:

- A base view that does a lot of joining and filtering based on some parameters that generates 'Table_A' with fk 'ProductId'
- N views that are generating additional info based on 'Table A' also with fk 'ProductId', lets assume I have just one that generates 'Table_B'
- A final view that left joins 'Table_A' with the N generated tables, for this example with 'Table_B'

I now want to merge all these queries/views together to just one and I do not know how to do that (syntax wise). And I also do not know what to search for to find an answer.
So a push in the right direction is highly appreciated.

To clarify a bit what I want to do, assume there is a view with a select query which produces 'Table_A'. I now want to replace the reference to 'Table_A' in the query from 'Table_B' with the original query:

```
SELECT `a`.`ProductId` AS `ProductId` ...more columns... 
FROM (`Table_A` `a` LEFT JOIN `other_table` `t` ON(`t`.`ProductId` = `a`.`ProductId`)) 
WHERE ...some conditions...
```

Comment: Hi sirloin, relevant answers require details. Including the queries may be a big step forward.

Comment: The actual queries are quite large and I wanted to keep it simple because I want to know about the technique how to merge two existing queries to one. Is that not possible without knowing the exact query?

Comment: I wouldn't , If it all works push into a procedure and walk away. on the other hand who can say if your approach is correct.